# Prove determinant of a Matrix using induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, determinant

So, let $A\in \mathbb{M}_n$. I know that (without prooving it yet :D) -
$\det A=\left\{
\begin{matrix}0 
 & n \text{ is odd}\\ 2
 & n \text{ is even}
\end{matrix}\right.$

$A =\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0&  .&  .&  .&  .&  0& 1\\ 
 1&  1&  0&  .&  .&  .&  .& 0\\ 
 0&  1&  1&  0&  .&  .&  .& .\\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .& .\\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .& .\\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .&  .& .\\ 
 0&  .&  .&  .&  .&  1&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  .&  .&  .&  .&  0&  1& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

By calculating $\det A$ using first column, I get $\det A=|A_{11}^M|-|A_{21}^M|$. I know that $|A_{11}^M|=1$ for every $n$, and that $|A_{21}^M|=1$ when n is odd, and $|A_{21}^M|=-1$ when n is even.

So far everything is clear. How do I put all of this into a proper proof?

Comment: OK I got this right - for $A_{21}^M$, if I swap each row with the row beneath it, with a total of $n-1$ swaps, I get a triangular matrix, where the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, multiplied by $(-1)^(n-1)$ row swaps.